# LINQ could not be translated. Call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

How can I compare a list sent to me for filtering with a list in my database?

I have a List called CandidateLanguage in my candidate entity.

And I get a list called LanguageSkills from outside to filter. Then, when I fetch my candidates, I want to make this comparison, but I get an error.

My code :

```
var entities = _context.Candidates
    .Include(p => p.CandidateLanguages)
    .Where(m => m.CandidateLanguages
        .Any(l => languageSkills
            .Any(c =>
                c.LanguageId == l.LanguageId &&
                c.Writing <= l.Writing &&
                c.Reading <= l.Reading &&
                c.Speaking <= l.Speaking
            )
        )
    )
    .AsNoTracking();
```

The error I received:

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: Using `Any( Any() ) with Linq-to-Objects will give you `O( n *m )` runtime - _that's bad_. IN Linq-to-SQL it would probablyh get optimized to a `WHERE IN` but that only works well for small collections.  Anyway, even if the Linq expression tree could be converted this query will likely run slowly because I suspect you don't have `INDEX` objects defined on _all_ of those columns youi're referencing now...

Comment: @Dai Thank you very much for the information. What can you recommend as an alternative to this query?

Comment: Your question, as-is, is still too vague for me to answer usefully. Please reword it such that it explains exactly what the `LanguageSkills` list is and what it contains - and when you say "filter" it's unclear which collection is meant to have items eliminated (is it `LanguageSkills` because you said you "had to filter" it) - or is it the `Candidates` pool (because that makes more sense...)?

Comment: Hi @Elchin, it is better for you to share the model design to us.  What if you filter outside: `var candidates = _context.Candidates.Include(p => p.CandidateLanguages).AsNoTracking().ToList();` and then modify to run your where clause code?

Comment: I have candidates. And it is filtered so that I only go to candidates who know the given languages. CandidateLanguages is a table that stores the languages known by the candidate. LanguageSkills is the parameter list I accept for the filter. For example, if LanguageId 1 will come on LanguageSkills, then candidates who know this language in the CandidateLanguages table should return only.

Comment: It is not translatable query, with EF Core up to version 8. You can use with local collections only `Contains`. I mean `languageSkills` is local collection. What we can do, it is only build LINQ query dynamically or use `FromSql`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, EF cannot translate a list of objects (languageSkills) to be used like that in a filter. You can only use collections of simple types. More complex comparisons against in-memory objects need to be done in memory.

We can do an initial filter based on the language IDs requested:

```
var languageIds = languageSkills.Select(x => x.LanguageId).Distinct().ToList();

var entities = _context.Candidates
    .Include(p => p.CandidateLanguages)
    .Where(m => m.CandidateLanguages
        .Any(l => laungageIds.Contains(l.LanguageId)))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();

entities = entities
    .Where(l => languageSkills.Any(c =>
            c.LanguageId == l.LanguageId &&
            c.Writing <= l.Writing &&
            c.Reading <= l.Reading &&
            c.Speaking <= l.Speaking))
    .ToList();
```

The first query runs against SQL and retrieves all candidates for the selected languages. From there we filter it down in memory to the exact matches. The caveat of this approach is that this could end up loading a significant amount of data.

A more complete approach if you are dealing with a lot of candidates to filter down and a relatively reasonable number of skill criteria would be to use a dynamic expression builder to build a `Where` expression based on the criteria. This will be used to compose an (AND-AND-AND) OR (AND-AND-AND) OR (AND-AND-AND) ... expression from your list of languageSkills. This can be done with `PredicateBuilder`, or manually composing an expression in a loop, or something like the DynamicWhere Nuget package.